# Guesses on fixed point existence

Tags: general-topology, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

Let $\mathcal{X} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a finite set and the mapping $\Phi : \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{X}$ be defined as follows:

$\Phi(x) := \{y \in \mathcal{X} \mid J(y,x) \leq J(z,x), \, \forall z \in \mathcal{X} \}$

with $J : \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ two-argument function. I'm not sure about the existence of a fixed point for $\Phi$, but I do not even have a suitable counterexample. Any suggestions/intuitions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: From the definition, it appears that $\Phi$ maps $X$ to the power set of $X$ so I don't see how it could have a fixed point.

Comment: @saulspatz to be precise, $\Phi$ maps each point $x \in \mathcal{X}$ into some $\mathcal{Y} \subseteq \mathcal{X}$

Comment: That's exactly what I said.  So how could $\Phi$ have a fixed point?

Comment: @saulspatz (Just for information) In this context, $x$ is a fixed point if $x\in \Phi(x)$.

Comment: @Song Thanks.  I wasn't aware of that usage.

Comment: @GuidoLaremi You can see more general result in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakutani_fixed-point_theorem. In view of the Rigel's answer, we cannot drop the assumption that the domain is compact and convex.

Comment: @Song Thanks for clarifying what is meant by fixed point in this context. The compactness is guaranteed by the finiteness of $\mathcal{X}$. But anyway, there is no convexity here, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without further assumptions I think you cannot guarantee the existence of a fixed point.
Consider, for example, $X= \{1, \ldots, m\}$ for some $m>1$, and let $J(i, j) := |i - (j+1)|$, if $j < m$, $J(i, m) := |i - 1|$.
Then $\Phi(j) = \{j+1\}$, if $j < m$, and $\Phi(m) = \{1\}$, and there is no $j \in \{1, \ldots, m\}$ such that $j\in \Phi(j)$.

If you prefer to use a finite subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n>1$, let $X := \{x_1, \ldots, x_m\} \subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and define the function $J$ as above (with obvious modifications, i.e. $J(x_i, x_j) := |i - (j+1)|$ if $j<m$, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the scalar example. I was wondering what "weak" regularity properties on $J$ may help to ensure the existence of a fixed point.

Comment: If $X$ is a finite set, you can give a look to this paper: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1134%2FS000143460707022X

Comment: I've already had a look to that paper, thank you in any case! To be honest, the scalar example does not make sense in my context, since I'm dealing with game theory. Since $J$ is a two argument function in the strategy space, the scalar case means that basically there is only one player playing the game. Hence I should assume $n > 1$, but I guess that if it does not work for $n = 1$, there is no hope for $n > 1$ :-(

Comment: I think you can modify the example in any dimension, see the edited answer.